# How can I dereference a constructor? 

Tags: php

Ideally I would like to do something like this....

```
$formElement->addValidator
(
    (new RegexValidator('/[a-z]/') )->setErrorMessage('Error')
    // setErrorMessage() returns $this
);
```

Of course PHP won't allow that, so I settle for this...

```
$formElement->addValidator
(
    RegexValidator::create('/[a-z]/')->setErrorMessage('Error')
);
```

And the code in the Base class....

```
static public function create( $value )
{
  return new static( $value );
}
```

I would *like* to go one step further and do something like this...

```
static public function create()
{
  return call_user_func_array( 'static::__construct', func_get_args() );
}
```

Again, PHP won't allow me to do this. I *could* code individual 'create' methods for each validator, but I want it to be a little more slick.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It is sad someone is forcing you to use a language that doesn't work with how you think.

Comment: I suggests to use a temporary variable instead of pseudo-singeltons/-factories just for the purpose of saving one line of code.

Comment: @Kingcrunch yeah, maybe, but nothing ventured, nothing gained :)

Comment: for anyone still coming to this question, it's worth pointing out that PHP 5.4 does support the dereferenced constructor syntax that the @tomwrong wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) from [Reflection API](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/book.reflection.php):

```
$class = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
return $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Comment: Brilliant, this definitely on the right track. I will post my actual solution when my 8 hour limit runs down.

Answer (score 9):

Corzin massively pointed me in the right direction, Reflection - (thanks Krzysztof).

Please note that late static binding applies, which is only a feature of **PHP >= 5.3**

The method of interest is **Validator::create()**.  It provides a work-around for the lack of ability to call methods on objects which have bee created inline (see my original question).

The base class...

```
class Validator
{
    ....
    static public function create()
    {
        $class = new ReflectionClass( get_called_class() );
        return $class->newInstanceArgs( func_get_args() );
    }

    public function setErrorMessage( $message )
    {
    ....
}
```

The extended class....

```
class RegexValidator extends Validator
{

    public function __construct( $regex )
    {
    ....
}
```

A usage example...

```
    $form
        ->getElement('slug')
        ->setLabel( 'Slug' )
        ->addValidator( RegexValidator::create('/[a-z]/')->setErrorMessage('Error') )
        ->addValidator( RequiredValidator::create() );
```

Comment: Oh, okay , shall I delete this post?

Comment: @yes123: He provided additional information and a solution, I don't see anything wrong with that. Though, a little more explanation to the code would have been nice.

Comment: @Bobby: i dont' see any added code except Cozin answer wrapped in a static method

Comment: @yes123: I don't agree, this is not just a wrapped function in a container class, it's place in the class is critical to the purpose and usage of the class.

Comment: @tom: that's the only place where you could put in those 2 line of code :D anyway it's ok feel free to leave it here you got +5 points for your answer